# Replace 0s with next non-zero value in column R

Tags: r, replace, fill

Someone else gave me a data set that looks kind of like this.

```
input = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,2)
```

What I need to do is fill the 0's with the next non-zero number (it will always be a 1 or 2).  Also, this next non-zero number needs to be filled be the next one (The last value can be anything because I am going to set it to NA anyway).

So the function should return this

```
> output =c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,NA)
> cbind(input,output)
      input output
 [1,]     0      1
 [2,]     0      1
 [3,]     0      1
 [4,]     0      1
 [5,]     1      2
 [6,]     0      2
 [7,]     0      2
 [8,]     0      2
 [9,]     0      2
[10,]     0      2
[11,]     0      2
[12,]     2      1
[13,]     0      1
[14,]     1      2
[15,]     0      2
[16,]     0      2
[17,]     2     NA
```

Thanks!

-- Edited Part --

The output only needs to be an array/vector (or whatever the proper term in R is).  The example I bound the 2 together to demonstrate the offset by 1 as well as the filling.  Thanks for the great answers guys

Comment: Is the expected output a matrix, data frame, or just the new output vector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
output=input[!!input][cumsum(!!input)+1]
#[1]  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  1  2  2  2 NA
```

We take advantage of how R coerces numbers to logicals. `as.logical(0:2)` will return `FALSE TRUE TRUE`. Zeros become `FALSE` and the other numbers are considered `TRUE`. Putting the negation exclamation point in front of `input` coerces it to logical. I could have written `as.logical(input)`, it's just a trick to save a few keystrokes. So we use that logical index to subset the non-zero values with `input[!!input]`. The cumulative sum of a logical index `cumsum(!!input)+1` creates a quick way to index on the change points when you add one to it. It helps to run each part separately.

Comment: You'll be even faster (maybe only on very long vectors) if you add an extra line to assign the double negation, something like `vl<-!!input; input[vl][cumsum(vl)+1]`. But it's only marginal, if you're big on the one-liner-ness :)

Comment: and just doing the full `as.logical` instead of the shortcut. I like the brevity

Comment: very elegant solution, +1

Answer (score 4):

Set the `0` values to `NA` and use `na.locf`:

```
input[input==0] <- NA
na.locf(input, fromLast=TRUE)
## [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2
```

From `?na.locf`:

> Generic function for replacing each NA with the most recent non-NA prior to it.

Comment: I still need to shift up the non-zero numbers by 1.  Please look at my output and yours, you have an extra leading 1

Comment: Exactly what I was about to suggest...!

Comment: Nevermind I guess I can just use the slide function at this point

Comment: @qwertylpc then just subscript it `[2:...]`

Comment: @smci won't the lengths be different

Comment: You should specify that na.locf is found in the zoo package.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

```
#find non-0s
x<-which(input!=0)
#replace 0s with subsequent nonzeros;
#  input[x] is the elements to replace
#  diff(c(0,x))-1 is the number of times to repeat
#    we need to pad x with a 0 to get initial 0s,
#    and we need to subtract 1 to ignore the nonzeros themselves
input[input==0]<-rep(input[x],diff(c(0,x))-1)
#replace nonzeros with the subsequent nonzeros
#  x[-1] removes the first element
#  we need to pad with NA as the final element
input[x]<-c(input[x[-1]],NA)
```

I'm looking again and it may be a bit cryptic; let me know if you'd like an ellaboration

---

Edit:

The above works perfectly fine for your `input`, but fails if there's any trailing `0`s. If there are trailing `0`s on your vector `v`, this is messier but works:

```
#as above
x<-which(v!=0)
#now, we need to integrate more NA replacement to this step
#  since we allow for 0s to finish v, also pad x with an end-of-vector marker
v[v==0]<-rep(c(v[x],NA),diff(c(0,x,length(v)+1))-1)
v[x]<-c(v[x[-1]],NA)
```

Even still, it's much faster (almost 4x) than @MatthewLundberg's suggestion (at the expense of readability). @PierreLafortune's answer reigns supreme, however. Still not really sure how it works...

```
test<-sample(0:2,size=1e6,rep=T,prob=table2(input,prop=T))
microbenchmark(times=100L,matt(test),mike(test))

Unit: milliseconds
       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 matt(test) 130.23987 130.70963 135.02442 131.23443 131.93079 183.73196   100
 mike(test)  36.27610  36.48493  36.66895  36.58639  36.73403  38.12300   100
 plaf(test)  22.18888  22.30271  23.08294  22.43586  22.65402  76.95877   100
```

Comment: Let me try to figure it out.  The first line gets indices of where we have non zero values.  The next line gets the values at these spots and the spaces between them, and uses repeat to space them out properly.  Not exactly sure how the last line works.

Comment: @PierreLafortune OK. It's not clear OP wanted a `data.frame` as output, so I'm just testing your assignment to output.

Comment: Thanks for your response too.  I was actually gonna mark it as the best answer, but as you pointed out Pierre's was the fastest (and most mind blowing)

Comment: I agree! 'twas an inspiration.